# C#, Process Viewer, which is service vs desktop app

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I'm not writing a process viewer, but need somewhat the same concept.
I can do

```
List<Process> allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
```

Question:
How can I tell which process is a normal process and which is a windows service?  I've dug through the properties of Process and not finding a flag of any sort.

Comment: [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller) class -- [Win32_Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service)

Comment: You have to look at the parent process.  Desktop apps are launched by Explorer and Services by the service control manager.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'm not looking if I'm the service or I'm running as a service..  Read the question again.    I'm asking how I can tell if something else is running as a service or not.

Comment: What I mean is, if you look at the `Win32_Service` class, the `ProcessId` property can link to the `ProcessId` of a Process object. The ServiceController class is useful because it lists the Dependencies.

Comment: Right.  The only way is to look at its parent process.

Comment: Looking at ServiceController, but have concerns and ServiceController doesn't hold ProcessID..    I found ManagementObjectSearcher might work better.  Jimi, yours gave me direction with Win32_Service, thanks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Process() class doesn't have Parent.  You would still have to go do PerfMon or ManagementObjectSearch to find the parent.     I believe my solution is a bit more simple and less overhead.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool IsService(Process p, out string serviceName)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    serviceName = "";

    string query = $"SELECT Name FROM Win32_Service WHERE ProcessId={p.Id}";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    {
        serviceName = obj["Name"].ToString();
        retVal = true;
        break;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: That works, for the main process hosting each service, but not for child processes it spawns.

Comment: You may also use [OpenThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) (with `THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION` as `DesiredAccess`) using the Process Threads collection, then call [GetProcessIdOfThread()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessidofthread) passing the previously returned handle (of course call `CloseHandle()` after).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I ended up moving to Win32_Service to pull Services and Win32_Process for all processes including Services..   My List then holds all processes with a flag that states if it's a service based on what is found in Win32_Service.   In Win32_Process it has Parent ID so I'm able to sort and setup the process for each, including services and their children.   I'll update my answer with a new method when I'm done with it as I'm trying to make the flow cleaner.   As am old school developer, I don't like over coding as most do these days.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, I'll take a look at that as well.